# Single product star rating reivews out of position

Tags: css, comments, woocommerce, rating-system

I recently changed my code so that the star ratings on the category page are floated to the left, but on the single-product reviews the rating is randomly floating.

The css I used to reposition the stars on [this](http://happyhealthymarket.com/) page is:

```
.star-rating {
position: absolute !important;
margin-left: 25px !important;
bottom: 0px;
float: left;
}

ul.products .star-rating
{
margin: 1.5em auto;
}
```

If you scroll down to the bottom of [this](http://www.happyhealthymarket.com/product/live-culture-kombucha-scoby/) page you will see that there are two random star ratings floating, one just above the double line and below the comment. And the other star ratings above the footer. Hopefully you can help, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You give star-rating absolute position, but the closest container with position relative is the #comment container. if you give position relative to .comment-text, I guess that's where you want it to be?

Comment: I gave the star-rating absolute to position the stars on the archive page. The comment-text made the top stars look better, but there is still another one floating down at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Where do you want that to appear? I guess you want to add postion relative to woocommerce-product-rating container, and adjust position of your stars

Comment: When I change the position to relative, it appears exactly where I want it. However this also moves the star-ratings on the [main](http://happhealthymarket.com/) page, I do not want those to change.

Comment: Good. If that's the case, you can give stars on this page another class name to overwrite CSS

Comment: I added this line of code to my css, it positions the stars correctly on both pages. However I still have that annoying star rating at the bottom! 

Code: 
`.single-product #reviews .star-rating {
position: relative !important;
}`

Comment: try give the stars at the bottom absolute position, and woocommerce-product-rating container relative position

Answer (score 0):

Changed my css code, see below:

```
li .star-rating {
position: absolute !important;
margin-left: 1.5em !important;
bottom: 0px;
float:left;
}

ul.products .star-rating
{
margin: 1.5em auto;
}    

.single-product #reviews .star-rating {
position: relative !important;
}
```